# if/else statements using cookies as condition

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm creating an if/else statement that is based on if certain cookies exist, but when I run the code it just gives out: 1000, 1000.

Note: I'm using a cookie plugin too at https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.

Here's the javaScript (only a small part of the actual code):

```
Cookies.get("options");
Cookies.get("options2");

if (Cookies.get('options'&& 'options2') == '1000', '1000') {
    alert("1000, 1000");
} else if (Cookies.get('options') && Cookies.get('options2') == '1100', '1000') {
    alert("1100, 1000");
} else if (Cookies.get('options') && Cookies.get('options2') == '1010', '1000') {
    alert("1010, 1000");
} else if (Cookies.get('options') && Cookies.get('options2') == '1001', '1000') {
    alert("1001, 1000");
} else if (Cookies.get('options') && Cookies.get('options2') == '1110', '1000') {
    alert("1110, 1000"); 
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is the following line:

`if (Cookies.get('options'&& 'options2') == '1000', '1000') {`

Working with two values doesn't work the way you seem to be trying. I would try something like this:

`if (Cookies.get('options') == '1000' && Cookies.get('options2') == '1000') {`

This is because Cookies.get() only accepts one cookie name at a time and returns the value for that one cookie, and you have to do each comparison separately.